# I have 4 monitors connected running windows. Seeking utility/mod of taskbar to display on 2 monitors only, and not on all 4 Monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, taskbar, tabs, desktop-customization

*Trying to find a solution for the following:*

I been using [+7 taskbar tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) for options such as ability to customize group groups or unpin certain tabs from groups and option to display seconds In the time clock. 7+ Taskbar is lacking one feature.  I have look extensively and I cannot find anything on nirsof that will work. Thought this [utility](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) might work on nirsoft but I was mistaken.

Currently the Windows 8 setting is to show taskbar on only one monitor or to show taskbar on all displays.

My Goal is I have **4 monitors** connected running windows 8.1. I am hoping that there is a utility to only show bottom taskbar on **2 monitors** only. For example Monitors 2 and 4 will have a bottom taskbar and Monitors 1 and 3 will not show any taskbar at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisplayFusion does this. Check [here](http://www.displayfusion.com/Help/?Version=6.0.0%20(beta%202)#contextmenu-taskbar) where they detail how to set up multi-monitor taskbar and then remove it on the ones you don't want it on.

In short. Install DisplayFusion, turn on multi-monitor taskbar from Settings > Taskbar. Click the Enable All Taskbars option, then right-click on the taskbar on the monitors you want it removed from, hover over the Multi-monitor Taskbar option, then the Position option, and click disabled.